# Lightning: How to change page title for lightning app?

Tags: html, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

Could you please share an idea how to change page title for lightning app?

Comment: any ideas or attempts you've already made we should not answer ? Please understand that short and limited questions like this show  very little effort from your side. That doesn't always motivate people to help you out.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Today you can add this:

document.title = "Your Title";

in your .app's init handler:

```
<aura:handler value="{!this}" name="init" action="{!c.init}"/>
```

in your app's controller:

```
init: function(component, event, helper) {
   document.title = "Your Title";
}
```

This happens a bit later than you would like so you will see Aura in the title for a short interval and then it gets replaced with Your Title.

There is a new feature being exposed in Lightning Components soon that lets you customize the app's "template" markup that will make this both trivial and eliminate the Aura -> Your Title "flash". template= for apps exists already in Aura open source so you can read about it at least - we were waiting on a few changes to the way templates work before exposing them via Lightning where we have to support them in a push update world. See https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/raw/master/aura_oss.pdf Creating App Templates to get a preview of what is coming to LC.

Comment: the feature to change title using template is documented but didn't work in my org https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apps_template_overview.htm I had "No COMPONENT named markup://MyAppTemplate found" error

Comment: Hi @Doug, do you have any more up to date information on this? I can't use this solution in a managed package, and I think the template is only for aura apps and not components. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221954/lightningactionoverride-set-page-title/221998#221998